# About Saura Tantra?

Tags: philosophy, tantra, surya

While exploring about Tantra, I came to know there is Saura Tantra too. It might be very ancient. So want to know the core philosophy and what are the principle Texts/Scriptures of Saura Tantra?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/TrcaBhaskaraByBhaskararayaR.G.Sathe

Comment: https://archive.org/details/baVz_saura-agama-tantra-of-prof.-shitala-prasada-pandey-yoga-tantra-grantha-mala-38-s

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no known surviving Saura āgamas. But thanks for sharing Tṛcabhāskara by Bhāskarāya, was unaware about it before @RakeshJoshi

Comment: paṭala (31-35) in [Devīrahasyam of Rudrayāmalatantra](https://archive.org/details/RudraYamaloktaShriDeviReshyamKapildevaNarayana/mode/2up), deal with pūjā, upāsanā, etc. relating to Sūrya. It also has a Sūrya sahasranāma.

Answer (score 0):

Details of soura tantra i.e. worship of surya, inititation, etc. are found in ***samba purANa*** and ***bhaviShya purANa*** :

[samba purANa](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/samba-purana-sanskrit-text-with-english-translation-naf481/) :

[image]

[bhaviShya purANa](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/complete-bhavisya-mahapurana-sanskrit-text-with-english-translation-in-3-volumes-aza329/) :

[image]

Comment: How are you sure mentioned things in these purana are tantric and not vedic ?

Comment: this might also confirm puranic sun worship is tantric - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/sun-worship-in-the-puranas/d/doc626722.html